# How can i get a list of all variables in the constructor or the variables values?

Tags: c#, winforms, logging

For example i have this in the constructor:

```
countDown = 0;
            Client.CachePolicy = policy;
            SatelliteClient.CachePolicy = policy;
            btn8 = new Button();
            btn8 = button8;
            timer11 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer11.Interval = 1000;
            timer11.Enabled = false;
            timer11.Tick += new EventHandler(timer11_Tick);
            automaticDoubleClick = false;
            this.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(Form1_MouseWheel);
            label18.Visible = false;
            filesSizeButtonSwitch = false;
            filesSizeDemoMode = false;
            paintDemoButtonSwitch = false;
            paintDemoMode = false;
            debugButtonSwitch = false;
            debugMode = false;
            timerdelay = 0;
```

And that's small part of what i have in the constructor.
I also have a logger i did and i use the logger like this:

```
Logger.Write("test");
```

What i want instead typing Logger.Write for each variable vlaue to make some loop that it will loop over all variables automatic get the values and write them automatic to the Logger.
Just for example:

```
Logger.Write(variables[i].ToString());
```

Something like this.

Is there anyway to do it ? I'm using WinForms Application.

Comment: @Jonesy reflection will not help in getting local variables at all, and nothing can give you values of local variables short of debugger interfaces...

Answer (score 0):

Create a `StackFrame` object for the current frame, call `GetMethod` to get a `MethodInfo` object for the current method, call its `GetMethodBody` method to get a `MethodBody` object and then use the `LocalVariables` property.  I don't know all the details because I've never done it myself but that's where you should start looking.

UPDATE: I investigated a bit further and it looks like my suggestion won't help because the `LocalVariableInfo` objects in the `LocalVariables` collection contain data about the local variables but not their values or a way to get their values.

Comment: This seems like more work than simply refactoring the code to be cleaner / less responsibility packed into a single class. Your suggestion also scares me a little.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, it's an answer to the question that was asked. Whether that question should have been asked is a different issue. Anyway, even code being well-written doesn't mean no tracing will ever be needed. My suggestion can be encapsulated in a single method that can then be called from anywhere, so it's not really all that much work at all. If you know what you're doing it would take a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

One simple idea is to add new method to your **Class**, where you have specified every variable used in the **constructor**. It's not that automatic, but works:

```
    private string GetVariables()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("timer11 = " + this.timer11.Interval.ToString() + "\n");
        sb.Append("timer11 = " + this.timer11.Enabled.ToString() + "\n");
        sb.Append("automaticDoubleClick = " + this.automaticDoubleClick.ToString() + "\n");
        sb.Append("label18.Visible = " + this.label18.Visible);
        // Add all needed variables ->

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Then for example you can use the Logger within your object as follows:

```
Logger.Write(this.GetVariables());
```

Or outside:

```
Logger.Write(YourObject.GetVariables());
```